# Can't Access Auth::check in my view in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel framework and trying to implement login system to my website. My web site has a landing page. Base on user login status I need to change this links like bellow.

```
<ul class="secondary_menu">
  @if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
  <li><a href="{{url('/logout')}}" >Logout</a></li>
  @else
  <li><a href="{{url('/login')}}" >Login or Register</a></li>
  @endif
</ul>
```

Here's the controller responsible for loading this view

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('public.index');
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error that saying that `Class 'Auth' not found`

I try adding `use Auth` and `use \Auth` as suggested in other slimier kind of questions in stackoverflow but did not works for me. What am i doing wrong. Isn't is possible to check call `Auth` from view ?

Comment: In your ```config/app.php``` file, is ```'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class``` in aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative to `Auth::` facade you can use global helper:

```
auth()->check();
auth()->user();
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me how can I check authentication for specific guard (in my case 'customer') ? because my web application has both public(customers) end and admin end (admin panel).

Comment: Just change `Auth::` to `auth()`. So`auth()->guard('customer')->check()` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, That fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code to use the Auth in your code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and then use it like:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` to controller didn't fix the issue. what do you mean by this if statement ? are you saying there's issue in blade syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```